# Indexable skiplist implementations using C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, skip-lists

I heard about a data structure called "indexable skiplist" here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

I have searched for many links and websites, but none of them provide the information about the implementations of it in C++. Some links have  expired or denied access. Can anyone help me with some resources ?

Comment: Are you looking for links to resourcex (which would be off-topic explicitly)? For somebody providing an implementation here (whcih would be off-topic for lacking focus)? Or would you like help with a specific problem you encountered while trying yourself (in which case it would lack focus on that specific problem and maybe a [mre] ) ?

Comment: yes, I meant I need some links or resources about it in C++.

Comment: Take a look here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116345/skip-list-implementation, there are some relevant links inside plus code example.

Comment: As I already mentioned, asking for resources outside of StackOverflow is off-topic, because it is considered to yield opinion-based answers only. [help/on-topic].